# Flex layout with ScrollView

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I've been making Layouts for Screens in React Native with Flexbox for a while now and hadn't run into any trouble until today when I had to make this very simple layout:

- A **header** section (not a NavBar).
- A **content** section → A ScrollView with a FlatList inside of it.
- A **footer** section.

I want the content section to be 3 times bigger than the Header and the Footer, so naturally I set the flex to 1 (header), 3 (content), 1 (footer).

No matter what, the content remains as if it has `flex: 1`.
The only way I could control the layout the way I wanted was to leave content's `flex: 1` and set both footer and header to `flex: 0.33`.

I suspect it might have something to do with ScrollView's **contentContainerStyle** prop which I set to `flexGrow: 1, flexShrink: 1`.

Here's a **[minimal example](https://snack.expo.io/SJIezEAEm)** which reproduces this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:**

I've been pointed out that **I shouldn't be using a ListView wrapped inside a ScrollView** since the following can happen:

- It might lead to some weird behaviors like `onEndReached` firing continuously.
- Wrapping the ListView inside the ScrollView makes the parent scroll action dominate the child scroll action which leads only ScrollView to scroll.

---

Okay, I'm not sure why this works, but found the solution after hours of trying:

After the step mentioned in **Update 1**, I added the following style `flexGrow: 0` to the **FlatList** inside the **ScrollView** and the content became centered and decreasing the content's size until it becomes scrollable works perfectly as well.

Basically this is the resulting code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>HEADER</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 6 }}>  // Change this to affect ScrollView size
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <FlatList
              data={listItems}
              renderItem={Item}
              keyExtractor={(index, item) => item}
              style={{ flexGrow: 0 }}  // This was the solution to centering
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>FOOTER</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Here's the final **[Working Solution](https://snack.expo.io/BkZhWo047)** if you'd like to try it.

---

**Update 1:**

Managed to control ScrollView size with Flex normally (that is using integer flex values as intended in the first place) by **wrapping ScrollView inside a View** with `flex: 1`.

The downside is that if I set the Scrollable section (content) to a flex value high enough so It's not scrollable anymore, content doesn't display centered. Not even if `justifyContent: 'center'` is applied.

Here's **[UPDATE 1 example](https://snack.expo.io/BJfkWsC4X)**.

Comment: did you look into the FlatList and ScrollView styles applied by default in react-native? https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/react-native/blob/4091984ff189b0b69deed0406327fdf84f7f9602/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L682 and https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/react-native/blob/4091984ff189b0b69deed0406327fdf84f7f9602/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L1849

Answer (score 0):

With minimal modification it works for me, I used this style:

```
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
      backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
      flex: 1,
    },
    header: {
      flex: 0.33,
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    scrollView: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    footer: {
      backgroundColor: 'lightpink',
      flex: 0.33,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

Full code >>> https://snack.expo.io/Hk9tbHR4Q

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Note that I've already stated that changing header and footer flex to decimals **does work**, but I wanted to prevent doing so because it's very tedious.  It'd be good to discover why it behaves like this with ScrollView.

Comment: @Franch Now I understand your question... This is because the ScrollView cannot decide its size by itself (this is special for the ScrollView, always has flex: 1). It has to wait for the other components to choose their seize (1, 3, 0.33...) and then the scrollView takes the rest!